# Javascript Constructor : How to find whether timer reached zero?

Tags: javascript

```
function MyGame() {
   var declaration
}
MyGame.prototype.initialize() {
   //methods and variable initialize
}
//other logics
```

I haven't completed this script. So i just typed how it will look.

countdown.js will look like this.

```
"use strict"

function Countdown() {
    this.seconds = 10;
    this.interval = null;
}

Countdown.prototype.startCountdown = function() {

var self = this;
this.renderTimer();
this.interval = setInterval(function() {

        if(!self.isNegative()) {
            self.seconds = self.seconds - 1;
            self.renderTimer();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

Countdown.prototype.isNegative = function() {
if(this.seconds <= 0) {
    return true;
    this.cancelInterval();
}
return false;
}
```

In that game javascript file, do i need to write another timeout function to read the value of countdown timer?

```
MyGame.prototype.checkgameOver = function() {

    var interval;
    var self = this;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(self.timer.getSeconds() <= 0 ) {
            self.gaemOver();
            clearInterval(interval);            
        }
    }, 1000);

 }
```

I want to stop the game when the timer is zero.
So, do i need to call the gameOver function from countdown timer?
What is the best way to end the game when the timer reaches zero?

Comment: add an else statement....

Comment: game.js and countdown.js - Both are different files. Do i need to pass the game.js object to countdown.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So change the logic where you are running the timer.

```
this.interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(self.isNegative()) { 
        //call game over code
    } else 
        self.seconds = self.seconds - 1;
        self.renderTimer();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: i have implement the script as you said. But i planned not to give any information about the game to countdown.js. But now i have to call the endgame function.

Comment: So use an event that triggers that the timer has hit zero and listen for that event in another part of your script.